# NSOperation userInfo Dictionary

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

Is there a way how to have a `userInfo` `NSDictionary` for a `NSOperation`?

Basically i want to assign an ID to an NSOperation, later i want to check, if this ID is already assigned to an NSOperation

```
- (void)processSmthForID:(NSString *)someID {

    for (NSOperation * operation in self.precessQueue.operations) {

        if ([operation.userInfo[@"id"] isEqualToString:someID]) {
            // already doing this for this ID, no need to create another operation
            return;
        }

    }

    NSOperation * newOperation = ...
    newOperation.userInfo[@"id"] = someID;

    // enqueue and execute

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSOperation` is meant to be subclassed. just design your own subclass.

> > The NSOperation class is an abstract class you use to encapsulate the code and data associated with a single task. Because it is abstract, you do not use this class directly but instead subclass or use one of the system-defined subclasses (NSInvocationOperation or NSBlockOperation) to perform the actual task.

[read here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html)

I agree with @Daij-Djan about the `userInfo` property addition.
This property could be implemented as an extension over `NSOperation` (refer to his answer for implementation).
However, The need for an identifier for an `NSOperation` is a specialization of the class (you could say that the new class is an `IdentifiableOperation`)

Comment: This is correct. You can simply have your subclass post a custom NSNotification and have whatever object register as an observer and keep a reference to any instance of your subclass. Very simple NSNotification stuff will do he trick.

Comment: Since NSOperation is an ABSTRACT class, it should be subclassed to perform any action and there you could implement whatever you like.

Comment: he didnt ask for Notifications .. of course this is doable without anything, but to add a property that does NOT FORM A SPECIALIZATION one doesn't subclass... that the difference between categories and subclasses. -- I agree it would be really wrong to add custom, specialized functionality here

Comment: You see the reason the docs were quoted, don't you? NSOperation is EXPECTED and INTENDED to be subclassed.

Comment: removed my downvote but uchugaka should read the docs ;) Expected / Inteded? -- they merely *as witth any abstract class* say that you don't USE it explicitly :D

Comment: I understand what u mean.  But adding a Catrgory affects all subclasses. It may have unintended side effects. In this case adding overhead.

Answer (score 1):

define a property on NSOperation like so:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

//category
@interface NSOperation (UserInfo)
@property(copy) NSDictionary *userInfo;
@end

static void * const kDDAssociatedStorageUserInfo = (void*)&kDDAssociatedStorageUserInfo;

@implementation NSOperation (UserInfo)

- (void)setUserInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kDDAssociatedStorageUserInfo, [userInfo copy], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kDDAssociatedStorageUserInfo);
}

@end
```

thaat gets you a userInfo on ANY NSOperation or subclass of that... e.g. NSBlockOperation or AFHTTPRequestOperation

DEMO:

```
    //AFNetwork test
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.de"]]];
    operation.userInfo = @{@"url":operation.request.URL};
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"download of %@ completed. userinfo is %@", operation.request.URL, operation.userInfo);
        if(queue.operationCount==0)
            exit(1);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"download of %@ failed. userinfo is %@", operation.request.URL, operation.userInfo);
        if(queue.operationCount==0)
            exit(1);
    }];
    [queue addOperation:operation];
```

Comment: No, it should always be subclassed. That is what it is designed for.

Comment: you want to add functionality to a class. COMMON functionality. you don't want to specialize it. that's why I agree in general and I wouldn't add a specific main method implementation to a base class, but I disagree in this case.

Comment: categories were meant for horizontal extensions. and this is no specialization ergo no subclass

Comment: As above, NSOperation is EXPECTED and INTENDED to be subclassed. That is the design of it. It would be pointless to add a category on it because you should always subclass it. Categories impact other subclasses running (including ones you didn't write but may be a part of an API you are using)

Comment: doesn't say that at all (it speaks about only about not using it :)) but I see it is pointless to argue. :)

Comment: Quote: Because it is abstract, you do not use this class directly but instead subclass or use one of the system-defined subclasses. --- So the category can be avoided (and its side effects) by just adding the property to the subclass.

Comment: using != Only intended OR expected to be subclassed - using means that you shouldn't instantiate it -- or ever work with an of it directly!